# Does anyone know how to download an extension package from composer, so it can be manually installed?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to manually install a magento 2 extension that only has a composer require command to install.

Is there a way to use the composer require command to download the extension dir? So it can be manually installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manually installation of the Module.

Download the extension via composer into **temp** dir. Open the registration.php from the dir.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendorname_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create folder in your magento `app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/`  and upload files in this dir.
And run setup upgrade and deploy command.

Comment: 1. Following your composer show command I created the below command.
composer show -a sparsh/magento-2-faq-extension | grep "dist"
2. I got the below output
https://repo.magento.com/archives/sparsh/magento-2-faq-extension/sparsh-magento-2-faq-extension-1.3.1.0.zip
When opening the URL in browser in step 2 it says “You haven't provided your Magento authentication keys”
How would I add the auth key to the repo output URL to allow me to download the package to my local drive?

Comment: @Alaldin In this case, you can't use the first (**1**) approach, use the second (**2**) approach instead. By the way, since your comment is in response to my answer, please make sure to add it in my answer, rather than in this answer. Otherwise, I won't receive a notification.

Answer (score 0):

There are severals approaches to achieve this. For the purpose of demonstration, I will assume you want to install the `markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth` extension package in `app/code`.

**1.** **Download the dist (packaged version) of the extension composer package.** Most of all extension packages has the **dist** available, you can run the following command to get the dist: `composer show -a vendor/package`

The command should be:

```
composer show -a markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth | grep "dist"
```

The output should look similar to this:

```
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth/zipball/224c68d85479938f06ab2400148778575784871c 224c68d85479938f06ab2400148778575784871c
```

You can open the URL in the output in a browser to download the compressed extension package.

**Note**: This approach requires that the extension composer package is a public composer package. If the package is a paid extension, you may get the "401 Authorization Required" error code and can't download the package.

**2.** **Download the extension composer package using composer and then copy the source code in the extension composer package to your `app/code`.**

Here, you have 2 approaches:

- Download the extension composer package in a directory outside of your project.
- Download the extension composer package in your project itself.

**2.1.** **Download the extension composer package in a directory outside of your project:**

Step 1: Create a new directory outside of your project
Step 2: Copy the `auth.json` and `composer.json` to the directory created previously.
Step 3: Download the extension composer package using composer:

```
composer require vendor/package
```

In my example, the command should looks similar to this:

```
composer require markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth
```

Step 4: Copy the source code in the extension composer package to your `app/code`.
Most of all extension providers place their Magento extensions (modules) inside the extension composer package directory (Example: `vendor/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth`). However, some extension providers place their Magento extension (module) in the **src** directory inside the extension composer package directory (Example: `vendor/sebastian/recursion-context/src`).
In this step, you will need to get the vendor and module namespace in the `registration.php` file of the extension (module) to create the extension directory in `app/code` directory. In my example, the registration.php file has the following content:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MarkShust_DisableTwoFactorAuth',
    __DIR__
);
```

Here, the vendor is MarkShust and the extension is DisableTwoFactorAuth.

You will need to create the extension directory, which has the following format: `app/code/Vendor/Extension`. In my example, the module path should be: `app/code/MarkShust_DisableTwoFactorAuth`. After creating the extension directory, copy the extension source code to that directory.

**2.2**. **Download the extension composer package in your project itself.**

In this approach, follows step 3 and step 4 in the approach 1 (**2.1**) and then revert the change in the `vendor` directory, `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files:

```
composer remove vendor/package
git checkout composer.json composer.lock
```